# Why I am getting Can't open /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions error?

Tags: bash, clamav, background-process

I got bash script from internet for for Running the Clamav Antivirus in Demon mode.

But am getting the below error.

Can't open /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

I checked /etc/rc.d/init.d/ directory there is no file named functions.

Mine is Ubuntu 12.04

My script is

```
# Source function library.
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

# Source networking configuration.
. /etc/sysconfig/network

[ -x /usr/local/sbin/clamd ] || exit 0

.....
```

Any idea?

Comment: The functions file is `/lib/lsb/init-functions`, but see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install `clamav` using `apt`:
`sudo apt-get install clamav*`, and you will not have these problems anymore.
What you have downloaded doesn't seem to be suitable for Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Yes. I have downloaded the clamav and used make install.What is the correct way to uninstall clamav?. Can I use apt-get remove clamav?

Comment: No, `make uninstall` from the directory from where you have installed it.